# GoLang / CGO: Problems calling Mach API host_statistics() from Go

Tags: go, cgo, mach

I use the following C code fragment to get the CPU load on OS X:

```
    #include <mach/message.h> 
    #include <mach/mach_host.h>
    #include <mach/host_info.h>

    [...]

    mach_msg_type_number_t  count = HOST_CPU_LOAD_INFO_COUNT;
    kern_return_t error;
    host_cpu_load_info_data_t r_load;

    mach_port_t host_port = mach_host_self();
    error = host_statistics(host_port, HOST_CPU_LOAD_INFO, (host_info_t)&r_load, &count);
```

I have tried to port this piece of code to Go after reading the cgo tutorial. The resulting code looks like this:

```
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mach/message.h>
#include <mach/mach_host.h>
#include <mach/host_info.h>
*/
import "C"

func main() {
    var err C.kern_return_t
    var host_info_out C.host_info_t
    var host_port C.mach_port_t = C.mach_host_self()

    count := C.mach_msg_type_number_t(C.HOST_CPU_LOAD_INFO_COUNT)

    err = C.host_statistics(C.host_t(host_port), C.HOST_CPU_LOAD_INFO, &host_info_out, &count)
}
```

However, when I try to build the code, I end up with the following error message

```
go build cputimes.go 
# command-line-arguments
cputimes.go:33: cannot use &host_info_out (type *_Ctype_host_info_t) as type *_Ctype_integer_t in function argument
```

I do not udnerstand why cgo complains about the type. The signature of host_statistics() is defined in the mach headers as:

```
 kern_return_t host_statistics
 (
      host_t host_priv,
      host_flavor_t flavor,
      host_info_t host_info_out,
      mach_msg_type_number_t *host_info_outCnt
 );
```

Comment: I couldn't find out the roots of the problem, but changing `var host_info_out` type from `C.host_info_t` to `C.integer_t` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The function prototype says that the third argument to `host_statistics` is a `host_info_t` variable, while you are passing a pointer to a `host_info_t` variable in your sample program.

Looking at the [`mach/host_info.h` header file](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2050.9.2/osfmk/mach/host_info.h), we can see that `host_info_t` is a pointer type:

```
typedef integer_t   *host_info_t;       /* varying array of int. */
```

That explains why you got the error message about a type mismatch with `integer_t`.

Your Go code doesn't really look equivalent to the C code when handling that argument.  You probably want something more like this:

```
...
var r_load C.host_cpu_load_info_data_t
...
err = C.host_statistics(C.host_t(host_port), C.HOST_CPU_LOAD_INFO, C.host_info_t(unsafe.Pointer(&r_load)), &count)
...
```

(you need to use the `unsafe` package to cast between the incompatible pointer types).